# async await inside script - API call with fetch doesn't return result

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am trying to retrieve weather data from an API by using a JavaScript script on the client side. This is how the code looks like:

```
  <script>
    async function fetchWeatherData(){
      var url = "http://www.7timer.info/bin/api.pl?lon=-3.57&lat=40.49&product=astro&output=json";
      var weather_data = await fetch(url);
      var weather_json = await weather_data.json();
      return weather_json.dataseries[0].temp2m;
    }
    document.write(await fetchWeatherData());
  </script>
```

Unfortunately this code doesn't work as I expected.
A very similiar Node.JS/Express works great on the server side:

```
export async function getTemperature(iata){
    let latLong = latLongAirports.find(el => el.iata === iata);
    var url = "http://www.7timer.info/bin/api.pl?lon=" + latLong.long + "&lat=" + latLong.lat + "&product=astro&output=json"
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const jsonTemperature = await response.json();
    return jsonTemperature.dataseries[0].temp2m;
}
```

What am I missing or not understanding between the client/server side codes?

Comment: I didn't downvote. Can you check if the latLong values are what you expect. `console.log()` before that. You might wanna add what is not working. Is there an error?

Comment: @TusharShahi The second snippet works fine. I just wanted to illustrate the difference between the codes. I am more interested in making the first snippet work. Thanks!

Comment: @connexo I tried:  var temperature = await fetchWeatherData();
    document.write(temperature); but doesn't work either

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the console of your browser?

Comment: @connexo that statement is missleading. `document.write` is most certainly the wrong choice in any situation, but having `document.write(await fetchWeatherData());` the `await` (assuming the use of the keyword would be correct in that context, which it likely is not based on the given code) would interrupt the execution until the Promise is resolved, and then the result would be passed to the `document.write`. So technically it would work, but it would clear the contents of the whole page.

Comment: document.write is probably a strange choice but it's not the problem here and that do not deserve a downvote.

Comment: @Joulss my guess for the downvote is (I didn't downvote) that the question lacks basic debugging, which would at least mean checking for error messages shown in the console of the browser and including/mentioning those. The usage of `await` would result in a SyntaxError in that case. (`Unfortunately this code doesn't work as I expected`, the code does not run at all, due to that SyntaxError.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @t.niese I will work on my asking skills :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the problem ist that you can´t use "[top level async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#top_level_await)" in normal script tags. you need to declare your script tag as `type="module"`. Then it will work like you expect it.

```html
      <script type="module">
        async function fetchWeatherData(){
          var url = "http://www.7timer.info/bin/api.pl?lon=-3.57&lat=40.49&product=astro&output=json";
          var weather_data = await fetch(url);
          var weather_json = await weather_data.json();
          return weather_json.dataseries[0].temp2m;
        }
        document.write(await fetchWeatherData());
      </script>
```